# how to test all funds are withdrawn from a contract with hard hat

Tags: solidity, hardhat

the function in the contract is

```
    function withdraw() external onlyOwner {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
```

the test I've started is

```
  it('Should withdraw all funds', async () => {
    const balance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);
    expect(ethers.utils.formatEther(await balance.toString())).to.equal(
      '9999.982579589843532242'
    );
    const setWithdrawTx = await greeter.withdraw();
    await setWithdrawTx.wait();
    expect(ethers.utils.formatEther(await balance.toString())).to.equal(
      '19999.9651591797'
    );
  });
```

and this is how I'm launching the contract

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    provider = ethers.provider;
    [owner, addr1, addr2, ...addresses] = await ethers.getSigners();
    const baseFactory = (await ethers.getContractFactory(
      'Greeter',
      owner
    )) as Greeter__factory;
    greeter = await baseFactory.deploy('hello');
    await greeter.deployed();
  });
```

The error is

```
AssertionError: expected '9999.982579589843532242' to equal '19999.9651591797'
```

Will the contract initially have no funds? hence the balance doesn't change? If so I guess I need a way to send some funds then try to withdraw it? How do I get the address of the balance?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the test `balance` remains constant. It isn't updated after the call to `withdraw`. It is likely you want to update the balance.

```
let balance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address);

expect(ethers.utils.formatEther(await balance.toString())).to.equal(
  '9999.982579589843532242'
);

const setWithdrawTx = await greeter.withdraw();
await setWithdrawTx.wait();

balance = await provider.getBalance(owner.address); 

expect(ethers.utils.formatEther(await balance.toString())).to.equal(
  '19999.9651591797'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the transaction gas fee.

```
  const balance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address); // owner balance
  const amount = await ethers.provider.getBalance(greeter.target); // contract balance

  const txReceipt = await greeter.withdraw();

  const receipt = await txReceipt.wait();
  const gasUsed = receipt.cumulativeGasUsed * receipt.gasPrice; // transaction gas fee

  // test balance of owner account after transaction
  expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(owner.address)).to.equal(
    balance - gasUsed + amount
  );

  // test balance of the contract after transaction
  expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(greeter.target)).to.equal(0);
```